# Window functions and distinct

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, distinct

I have the following table.

```
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 code     | text                        |           | not null | 
 price_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 price    | double precision            |           | not null |
```

I need to use the data in this table to create a candlestick chart that will have 6-hour candlesticks. Each candlestick is represented by the fields `{ x, open, close, low, high }` where x is the UNIX timestamp of the beginning of the period.

The following query works, but using `distinct` causes the query to take longer. Usually, when people don't want to use distinct, they use `group by` instead, but I can't use that with the window functions and I'm not sure it would help anyway. Is there a way to eliminate the use of distinct in this query to make it faster and still return the same results?

```
with price_quotes as (
        select
            extract (epoch from price_at) - (extract (epoch from price_at) % extract (epoch from '6 hours'::interval)) as period_begin,
            extract (epoch from price_at) as quote_time,
            price
        from quote)
select distinct
    period_begin as x,
    first_value (price) over (partition by period_begin order by quote_time asc) as open,
    last_value (price) over (partition by period_begin order by quote_time asc rows between current row and unbounded following) as close,
    min (price) over (partition by period_begin) as low,
    max (price) over (partition by period_begin) as high
from price_quotes
order by x asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using window functions, which don't reduce the number of result rows, and then `DISTINCT`, which does, it would be better to use aggregate functions that do both in a single step.

We need aggregate functions for the first and last value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION first_not_null(anyelement, anyelement) RETURNS anyelement
   LANGUAGE sql AS 'SELECT coalesce($1, $2)';

CREATE AGGREGATE first(anyelement) (
   SFUNC = first_not_null,
   STYPE = anyelement
);

CREATE FUNCTION second_not_null(anyelement, anyelement) RETURNS anyelement
   LANGUAGE sql AS 'SELECT coalesce($2, $1)';

CREATE AGGREGATE last(anyelement) (
   SFUNC = second_not_null,
   STYPE = anyelement
);
```

Now you can write

```
WITH price_quotes AS (
   SELECT date_bin('6 hours', price_at, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') AS period_begin,
          EXTRACT (epoch FROM price_at) AS quote_time,
          price
   FROM quote
)
SELECT period_begin,
       first(price ORDER BY quote_time) AS open,
       last(price ORDER BY quote_time) AS close,
       min(price) AS low,
       max(price) AS high
FROM price_quotes
GROUP BY period_begin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of window functions and normal `group by` on the same partitioning, rather than using `distinct`. This means the optimizer can rely on the required sort not changing.

You can use either `min` or `max` on the windowed values, it makes no difference.

```
with price_quotes as (
        select
            extract (epoch from price_at) - (extract (epoch from price_at) % extract (epoch from '6 hours'::interval)) as period_begin,
            extract (epoch from price_at) as quote_time,
            price
        from quote
),
windowed as (
    select
        period_begin,
        price
        first_value(price) over (partition by period_begin order by quote_time asc) as open,
        last_value (price) over (partition by period_begin order by quote_time asc rows between current row and unbounded following) as close,
    from price_quotes
)
select
    period_begin as x,
    min(open) as open,
    min(close) as close,
    min(price) as low,
    max(price) as high
from windowed
group by
  period_begin
order by
  x;
```